# Infragistics webcombo Typeahead suggest

Tags: asp.net, infragistics, webcombo

I am using `infragistics webcombo` with the `typeahead suggest`.

The problem is that I am able to reach the `WebCombo1_InitializeDataSource` using the `xmlReq`, but the data is not visible in the `webcombo`.

Below is the piece of code I am using:

```
<igcmbo:WebCombo ID="WebCombo1" runat="server" EnableXmlHTTP="True" Editable="True"
                            ComboTypeAhead="Suggest">
                            <Columns>                              
                            <ClientSideEvents EditKeyUp="WebCombo1_EditKeyUp">
                            </ClientSideEvents>
                        </igcmbo:WebCombo>
```

Javascript function :

```
function WebCombo1_EditKeyUp(webComboId,newValue,keyCode) 
   {
       var oWebCombo1=igcmbo_getComboById(webComboId)

        xmlReq = null;
        if(window.XMLHttpRequest) xmlReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
            else if(window.ActiveXObject) xmlReq = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");                          

        var search=newValue&&newValue.length&&newValue.length>0?newValue:"";                        
        xmlReq.open("GET","ActivityManagement.aspx?searchString="+search,true);    
        xmlReq.send(null);
   }
```

Code behind :

```
void WebCombo1_InitializeDataSource(object sender, Infragistics.WebUI.WebCombo.WebComboEventArgs e)
{
    string str = "";
    if (this.Request.QueryString["searchString"] != null)
    {
        str = this.Request.QueryString["searchString"].ToUpper();
    }
    else str = "00";
    DataTable dtProducts = OperationsDataAccess.GetProductList(str);
    string rowFilter = "DeleteFlag = 0";
    dtProducts.DefaultView.RowFilter = rowFilter;
    WebCombo1.DataSource = dtProducts.DefaultView;
    WebCombo1.DataTextField = "Name";
    WebCombo1.DataValueField = "Id";
    WebCombo1.DataBind();
    WebCombo1.DropDownLayout.RowSelectors = RowSelectors.No;        
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by simply setting the following properties of the `webcombo`:

```
EnableXmlHTTP="True" 
Editable="True"
ComboTypeAhead="Suggest"
```

And bind the web combo with the datasource in the `InitializeDataSource` event of the webcombo
and also bind the webcombo in the `page_load` when the `page.ispostback` is true .

Implement the search logic in your stored procedure, e.g. `select * from employee where emp_name like 'a%'`.

This will retrieve the records as and when you keey in the data.